# Angular get difference function object key

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to compare two or multiple objects using `difference()` function and then use the object(s) key value to push into an array of just url's, but I can't use dot syntax on an object for some reason any hints?

array **this.stores**

```
[
  {
    name: "Google Play"
    url: "https://play.google.com"
  }
]
```

array **result**

```
[
  {
    name: "Google Play"
    url: "https://play.google.com"
  },
  {
    name: "Steam Store"
    url: "https://store.steampowered.com"
  }
]
```

I'm comparing these 2 arrays of objects like this:

```
const storesDifference = difference(result, this.stores);
// works as it should stores 'Steam Store'

console.log('difference', storesDifference.url);
// I'm trying to return URL key using dot syntax but without any success
```

Comment: whats the definition for `difference` function?

Comment: Creates an array of unique array values not included in the other provided arrays using SameValueZero for equality comparisons.

Comment: Indeed. The problem is probably in your difference function, which only returns the name, not the full object.

Comment: Ok got it, is there any other similar function or method I could use instead of difference where I could have access to the full object?

Comment: you can use filter for that

Comment: You question does not include any error message, do you get any?

Comment: used filter function and it worked, thank you all for your quick responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to solve this problem using filter function. Works as i wanted.
see below:

```
const array3 = this.stores
        .filter((x) => !result.includes(x))
        .concat(result.filter((x) => !this.stores.includes(x)));
```